# Python script file missing in Singularity image

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, dockerfile, singularity-container

In AWS, created a docker image with a python script to print a string(`basicprint.py`)

docker file:

```
FROM python

COPY ./basicprint.py ./
CMD ["python", "basicprint.py"]
```

It works fine then saved docker image as `.tgz` file.

copy that `.tgz` file in to my local.

I converted docker image(.`tgz`) into `singularity` image by using

```
singularity build sing_image.sif docker-archive://filename.tgz
```

it was successfully created `sing_image.sif`

```
singularity run sing_image.sif
```

It throws an error : `basicprint.py: No such file or directory`

Any suggestions on correct method of conversion without missing the file.

Comment: Can you provide the outputs for `docker build`, `docker run`, `docker save`, `singularity build` and the contents of `basicprint.py`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you put your file under the very root. `singularity` **removed your file during conversion and cleaning**. [Similar issues have been reported](https://github.com/apptainer/singularity/issues/2538) and are, in general, *expected when working with containers*.

This slightly modified image

```
FROM python:3.11-slim
COPY ./basicprint.py ./
CMD ["ls"]
```

demonstrates that the file lands under the linux root:

```
(base) maciej.skorski@kaggle-cpu-maciej:~/docker-debug$ docker build . --tag test-sing
(base) maciej.skorski@kaggle-cpu-maciej:~/docker-debug$ docker run -it test-sing
root@ed8e3545a00b:/# ls
basicprint.py  bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

Now, let me **demonstrate the working version**. Importantly, [*follow best Docker practices and use the working dir*](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#workdir)

```
# Dockerfile
FROM python:3.11-slim-bullseye

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src
WORKDIR /usr/src
COPY ./basicprint.py /usr/src/

CMD ["python", "/usr/src/basicprint.py"]
```

where the sample Python script is

```
# basicprint.py
print('Welcome to my Docker!')
```

Then I build and test on `Debian GNU/Linux 10` with `Docker 20.10.17` and `Singularity 3.11`:

```
(base) maciej.skorski@kaggle-cpu-maciej:~/docker-debug$ singularity --version
singularity-ce version 3.11.0+277-gcd6fa5c0d

(base) maciej.skorski@kaggle-cpu-maciej:~/docker-debug$ sudo docker build . --tag test-sing:latest
Successfully tagged test-sing:latest

(base) maciej.skorski@kaggle-cpu-maciej:~/docker-debug$ docker save test-sing:latest --output test-sing.tgz

(base) maciej.skorski@kaggle-cpu-maciej:~/docker-debug$ sudo singularity build test-sing.sif docker-archive:test-sing.tgz
...
INFO:    Build complete: test-sing.sif
(base) maciej.skorski@kaggle-cpu-maciej:~/docker-debug$ sudo singularity run test-sing.sif
Welcome to my Docker!
```

Under the same software, I reproduced your error. So I think it has been solved! If you need any further assistance, we can set up a shared Virtual Machine with GitHub Codespace to make it fully reproducible.

Comment: I am glad that I could help. The more I work with containers, the more I see how important it is to pay attention to cleaning parts :-)

Answer (score 1):

For testing, you could use a [def file, using `%file`](https://docs.sylabs.io/guides/3.7/user-guide/definition_files.html#files) instead of the Dockerfile:

> The `%files` section allows you to copy files into the container with greater safety than using the %setup section.

In your case, create a `Singularity.def` file with:

```
Bootstrap: docker
Registry: docker.io
Namespace: library
From: python

%files
    basicprint.py /opt/

%runscript
    exec python /opt/basicprint.py
```

Check if that approach is working with:

```bash
singularity build sing_image.sif Singularity.def
singularity run sing_image.sif
```

Regarding your Dockerfile, try and use a different folder, again for testing:

```
FROM python

COPY ./basicprint.py /app/
CMD ["python", "/app/basicprint.py"]
```

Then:

```bash
docker build -t my-python-image .
docker save my-python-image:latest | gzip > my-python-image.tgz
singularity build sing_image.sif docker-archive://my-python-image.tgz
singularity run sing_image.sif
```

Check also the `.sif` file includes your file: `singularity exec sing_image.sif ls /app`.